# How to convert xvk to svk?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I use cardano-address cli export extended private key, but i want to use it with cardano-cli command, how to convert it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have created your `cardano-wallet` wallet using a mnemonic, you can restore a private key from it.

An excellent tool for this is [`cardano-addresses`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses).

1. Generate your root private key.

```
cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
root_xsk1hqzfzrgskgnpwskxxrv5khs7ess82ecy8za9l5ef7e0afd2849p3zryje8chk39nxtva0sww5me3pzkej4rvd5cae3q3v8eu7556n6pdrp4fdu8nsglynpmcppxxvfdyzdz5gfq3fefjepxhvqspmuyvmvqg8983
```

2. Generate your payment verification key for the first address. Notice here, the `/0/0` is the address index, increase the last digit to generate your other addresses.

```
cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/0/0 < root.xsk | cardano-address key public --with-chain-code > addr.xvk
addr_xvk1grvg8qzmkmw2n0dm4pd0h3j4dv6yglyammyp733eyj629dc3z28v6wk22nfmru6xz0vl2s3y5xndyd57fu70hrt84c6zkvlwx6fdl7ct9j7yc
```

You should be able to use your payment key to sign a transaction using `cardano-cli`.

3. Create your payment address to double check it is correct.

```
cardano-address address payment --network-tag testnet < addr.xvk > payment.addr
addr_test1vp2fg770ddmqxxduasjsas39l5wwvwa04nj8ud95fde7f7guscp6v
```

Comment: Sign payment key (xxx.skey) generated by cardano-cli is a json file, in your case addr.xvk file is not a json file, is there any command line tool i can use to convert addr.xvk to a standard json file to meet the cardano-cli 's demand ?